# Cannot send a message inside another message chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I am getting a trouble about passing  message inside background page of chrome extension.

**In content page**

I send a message and wait for a response from background page:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"name": "Calling"}, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**In background page**

I have an event listener to listen message from content page:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.name == "Calling") {
            doTask().then(function (message) {
                sendResponse(message);
            });
            return true; // Make respond asynchronously
        }
    }
);
```

Inside "Calling" event Listener, i call the function `doTask()` which return a promise:

```
var doTask = function(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"name": "DoTask"}, function (response) {
            resolve(response);
        });
    });
};
```

Inside `doTask()` i send another message "DoTask", and wait for response.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.name == "DoTask") {
            var message = "Task has done!";
            sendResponse(message);
            return true; // Make respond asynchronously
        }
    }
);
```

I expect "Task has done!" will be printed in content page, but nothing appears! When debugging i realize "DoTask" event listener cannot receive any message.

What wrong here? Thank you.

P/S: I make sure that all scripts are injected in `manifest.json`

Comment: The code is correct. Make sure the content script is actually injected: you need to reload the tab or reinject via chrome.tabs.executeScript after you reloaded your extension.

Comment: One note though, `doTask` uses chrome.runtime.sendMessage which sends a message to another extension page, which must be different from the page that sends the message (to send to the same page simply extract onMessage callback as a separate function and call it directly). If you want to send it to a content script, use chrome.tabs.sendMessage with tabId as the first parameter.

Comment: So, it's impossible to send message in the same extension page? And i have to move the "DoTask" event listener to another extension page?

Comment: Simply call the function directly, see [chrome.runtime.sendMessage error in Chrome version 57.0.2987](//stackoverflow.com/a/43066875)

Comment: Another time, please use one code block per file. Don't break your files into separate code blocks per function. It is *much* easier to follow code when we can be *certain* what is grouped with what. We're all very familiar with reading code. We usually, don't need to be lead through the the code with the different functions interspersed with expository text. If such text is needed for someone to understand your code, then it should be contained as comments in the code so anyone reading the actual code will be able to understand it.

Comment: Yes, as stated, messages are not received in the same page/script from which they are sent. If they were, that could result in a variety of issues. The most obvious is that if you unconditionally sent a message in response to any message received, then you would end up in a loop which locks up the browser (or at least that process), where you continuously send a message in response to the message you just sent. If you want to play around where this can happen, you can run your code in [Firefox versions < 51](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage).